# After deleting the file for migration i am left with this message 'Migration not found'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have created by a mistake 2 migrations in my laravel project, using the `php artisan make:migration` command called `2018_03_30_075929_drop_products_tags_table` and `2018_03_30_075242_create_products_tags_table` and then i have deleted the files.

Now everything i run the command `php artisan migrate:refresh` I am get this error

```
Migration not found: 2018_03_30_075929_drop_products_tags_table
Migration not found: 2018_03_30_075242_create_products_tags_table
...
```

And i tried to run `php artisan migrate:reset`, but I am getting the same error. How can I fix this, because it is driving me insane :(

Comment: Just remove your migration files name from your migrations table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is you have some migrations in your database

go to your database delete the `migrations` table manually.

then you can create a migration table in your database

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

This will create a new migration table in your database.

then you can run

```
php artisan migrate
```

Hope this helps

Comment: can i delete the file and the db row in the migrations table using `php artisan`?

Comment: yess You can delete the file and entries from migration table.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete `tables` from database
2. Delete `migrations name` from `migrations table`

In this scene:

Delete product_tags table. Then, delete

`2018_03_30_075929_drop_products_tags_table`,

```
2018_03_30_075242_create_products_tags_table
```

rows from migration tables.

Answer (score -1):

You can delete all tables from database and migrate them again by this command:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

Comment: i already wrote that when i write this command i get this error